# Deduplicate table data based on column value in another row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing two columns src & dest, the data looks like this in the table:

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjEfz.png)

The requirement here is to deduplicate the data such that only one record exists where the dest column has a value populated as a src column or no value at all in the src column.

For example for the above data, below output should be shown by the sql query:

[output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM3DJ.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: Not much detail to go on here for sure but maybe you just need a left join between these tables and then a where clause to find the rows where the left joined table is null?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. This may get you what you want:

```
select * from T
where src  not in (select dest from T)
   or dest not in (select src  from T);
```